# ¿En que momento se rompio la Matrix? Kotlin ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es copiar una lista para que pueda modificarla sin que los datos ingresados al crear la lista original no se pierdan. Entonces el problema que sucede es que cuando borro un elemento de la lista "ordenes" dentro de la lista "pedidos2" NO SE COMO se borra el valor de las dos listas

```
val pedidos = arrayListOf(pedido0, pedido1, pedido2)

val pedidos2 = ArrayList(pedidos.map { it.copy() })

print(pedidos[1].ordenes.size)
println(pedidos2[1].ordenes.size)

pedidos2[1].ordenes.removeAt(0)

print(pedidos[1].ordenes.size)
print(pedidos2[1].ordenes.size)
```

En este caso se ve que utilizo

```
ArrayList(pedidos.map { it.copy() })
```

pero e probado con

```
ArrayList<Pedido>().apply { addAll(pedidos) }
for (i in pedidos) pedidos2.add(i)
```

Si alguien me podría explicar por que pasa esto y la forma en que pueda conseguir dos listas iguales seria buenísimo, se que realmente parece super simple pero no se que onda.

[image: Aca esta el mini testeo que hice]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es aquí:

```
{ it.copy() }
```

#### ¿Por qué?

`copy` es un método añadido por el compilador a todas las `data class`, y hace una copia **superficial**.

> Una copia superficial de un objeto no hace copias de otros objetos que este pueda tener dentro, sino que copia su referencia.

Es decir, teniendo una hipotética clase `Pedido`, y una instancia:

```
data class Pedido(val ordenes: List<Orden>)

fun main() {
    val pedido = Pedido(listOf(Orden()))
}
```

Si copias una instancia de `Pedido`, la variable `ordenes` no es nueva, es la misma para ambas instancias de `Pedido`:

```
pedido.ordenes === pedido.copy().ordenes   // da true, son la misma instancia
```

**Si le quitas un elemento a `pedido.ordenes` el cambio repercutirá en todas las copias de `pedido` que hayas hecho, porque su variable `ordenes` es común en todos ellos.**

Así que una solución que se me ocurre es que copies los elementos de `ordenes` manualmente, cada vez que copias un `Pedido`:

```
val pedidos 2 = pedidos.map { it.copy(ordenes = mutableListOf<Orden>().apply { addAll(pedido.ordenes)})}
```

Comment: Wow, gracias por la respuesta, voy a probar la opción que me dijiste pero tenia esperanzas de que exista una solución mas practica